# Get index of ListView item when RadioButton on one row is clicked in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am implementing `4 RadioButtons` in one `ListView row` and binding them with the model properties. The problem is when the user changes the pre-setted property and the `CheckedChanged event` fires, how can I get on which `row(Index)` the user has changed the property?

Here is my Implementation of ListView.

```
<ListView x:Name ="personlist" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" ItemSelected="personlist_ItemSelected" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="3*,*,*,*,*" BackgroundColor="{Binding RowColor}">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <RadioButton Value="Travel" IsChecked="{Binding Travel, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <RadioButton Value="Reading" IsChecked="{Binding Reading, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <RadioButton Value="Sports" IsChecked="{Binding Sports, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <RadioButton Value="Dance" IsChecked="{Binding Dance, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In .xaml.cs

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // I want to get an index of the list item here.
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it? this way or other.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `BindingContext`

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var button = (RadioButton)sender;
   var item = (MyClassName)button.BindingContext;
}
```

`item` will be the object that is bound to that row in the `ListView`

Comment: It worked, Thank you. But I don't understand how RadioButton object can be cast into the custom class definition? Can you please explain?

Comment: you are not casting the RadioButton, you are casting it's BindingContext property